# Symfony2: How to override radio_widget block in expanded choice field?

Tags: symfony, twig

I'm create create a custom form type for show stars rating, (basicaly five radio buttons). I create a custom block for render:

```
{% block star_rating_widget %}
    {% spaceless %}
        <div {{ block('widget_container_attributes') }}>
            {% for child in form %}
                    {{ form_widget(child) }}
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    {% endspaceless %}
{% endblock %}
```

This block render five radio buttons fine using default radio_widget block.

```
{% block radio_widget %}
    {% spaceless %}
        <input type="radio" {{ block('widget_attributes') }}{% if value is defined %} value="{{ value }}"{% endif %}{% if checked %} checked="checked"{% endif %} />
    {% endspaceless %}
{% endblock radio_widget %}
```

I need to know how to override radio_widget block for add some classes and attributes, but only when render inside star_rating_block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass variables to the `form_widget` through the second argument. You would basically allow a set of options in your custom type and pass them through the twig function.

```
{{ form_widget(child, {attr: {class: classNameVar}}) }} {# passing some classes through the variable classNameVar
```

You can find more information in [the documentation about twig template form function and variable reference](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/twig_reference.html#form-widget-view-variables).

In the same documentation, you can find information about the different [form variables](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/twig_reference.html#more-about-form-variables).

Answer (score 4):

Possible solution:

```
{% block radio_widget %}
    {% if "custom_widget" in form.parent.vars.block_prefixes %}
        // custom view 
    {% else %}
        // default view from form_div_layout.html.twig 
    {% endif %} 
{% endblock radio_widget %}
```

Comment: Good, but should be just "custom" (block prefix) without the  "_widget" part. And default view can be {{- parent() -}}